# How to check if the URL to the database is valid?

Tags: java, mysql, regex, path

In my application I'm using MySQL as the RDMS and I'm trying to connect to the database with the usual classes under `java.sql`.

I've a constructor in this class that is responsible for connecting or creating the database which accepts a parameter to specify the database path.

I would like to do some checks on the string passed to this constructor to check if it's a valid URL path. Currently, I'm using the following code, but I'm not sure if there's something that I'm forgetting or if it can be improved, maybe my simply checking using a regular expression.

```
private boolean isValidDBName(String dbName) {
    return dbName != null && !dbName.isEmpty() && dbName.startsWith("jdbc:mysql://") && dbName.endsWith("/");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion using regular expression is better way. There is a good topic about URLs and regular expressions.
[What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

-- Edit

You can use something like this:

```
^jdbc:mysql:\/\/ [your pattern] \/$
```